# jQuery Appended iFrame IE Only Throwing MS Ajax Could Not Be Parsed Error

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

On an Aspx page, I have this markup (setup for a jQuery UI dialog):

```
<div id="modal_showNewlyGeneratedPasscode" class="hide">

</div>
```

I do not have the iFrame inside the  because that was giving me all kinds of MS Ajax errors.  So, when an updatePanel is triggered, I dynamically put an iFrame in the above :

```
$('#modal_showNewlyGeneratedPasscode').append('<iframe src="Popup.aspx" height="240" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" />');
```

On FireFox and Chrome, this is fine - the iFrame displays inside the jQuery UI dialog, but on IE only it is throwing an Ajax exception:  Sys.Webforms.Pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception the message received from the server could not be parsed

*Other key details*:
- Popup.aspx is on the same domain as the page it is being called from, so cross-domain scripting is not the issue.
- The above  is not inside any UpdatePanel itself.
- Using the debugger, I've discovered that this error is occurring before the Popup.aspx page's Page Load is even hit. So I suspect that Ajax is erroring due to the dynamic insertion of the iFrame through jQuery.
- We do have a handler set up like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="PageScriptManager" OnAsyncPostBackError="AsyncPostBackError" runat="server">
   <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="../js/AjaxErrorHandler.js" />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: I found this link; it might be useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. I greatly appreciate it. However, I resolved this yesterday.

It turns out that I was setting an ASP hidden field to the value of the iFrame HTML, and IE Ajax security didn't like that. I simply took that out, and it ran!